# Debug Sockets with Android device using charles

Tags: android, sockets, websocket, charles-proxy

I am using Charles to debug api data everything works fine, but if I need to debug sockets via Charles is there any procedure to do that because I can't see any websocket data in cells while debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to intercept web socket traffic in Charles, "SOCKS proxy" should be enabled (by default, it is turned off).

In Charles, go to "Proxy - Proxy Settings" panel, and enable the "SOCKS proxy":

[image]

It's done. Here is an example of web socket traffic in Charles:

[image]

Comment: If you thought like me that you then have to switch the client device to use the socks proxy port instead, you don't -- somehow it just works with the device still using port 8888 as its proxy